# why parent class property is showing undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function Abc(){
  this.a ="naveen"
}

Abc.prototype.getName =function () {
  return this.a;
}

function Pqr() {
  this.b ="bn"
}

Pqr.prototype = Object.create(Abc.prototype);
Pqr.prototype.constructor = Abc;

var a = new Pqr();
console.log(a.a);
console.log(a.getName());
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

I am trying inherit the property from parent to child using `object.create` but this show undefined why ?

**output why ?**

```
undefined
undefined
{"b":"bn"}
```

Comment: The `Abc` constructor is never called, so `this.a` is never assigned a value.

Comment: how I will get the values

Comment: function Pqr() { Abc.Call(this);
              this.b ="bn"
}. Try this may this help.

Answer (score 0):

You code is actually assigning the function `Abc` to a new function `constructor` of `Pqr`. This `constructor` function is not the actual constructor function of `Pqr` that is why `this.a = "naveen"` is never called(since it is not a constructor function of Pqr so not invoked implicitly). To make that work you need to call the `constructor` function like `a.constructor();` before accessing the values of object `a`.

```js
function Abc(){
  this.a ="naveen"
}

Abc.prototype.getName =function () {
  return this.a;
}

function Pqr() {
  this.b ="bn"
}

Pqr.prototype = Object.create(Abc.prototype);
Pqr.prototype.constructor = Abc;

var a = new Pqr();
a.constructor();
console.log(a);
console.log(a.getName());
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: instead of using these two line `Pqr.prototype = Object.create(Abc.prototype);
Pqr.prototype.constructor = Abc;` if I try to use only one line `Pqr.prototype = new Abc()`

Comment: in that case my values is printed .so what is best way to inherit ? using `Òbject.create` or  `new  fun()`